# React Router for Unauthenticated User

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using react router in my project. I am trying to protect authenticated user pages from unauthenticated users.

My code is like below

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
            <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />

            if(Auth.isAuthenticated()) {                
                <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
            }
            else {
                <Redirect to="/" />
            }
        </Switch>
    </Router>, 
    document.getElementById('root'));
```

But this `<Redirect to="/" />` is not working.

**UPDATE**

I made another component like below

`Authentication.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Auth from '../services/Auth';
import { Redirect} from "react-router-dom";

const memberAreaHOC = WrappedComponent => {
    class Authentication extends Component {
        render() {
            if ( ! Auth.isAuthenticated()) {
                return <Redirect to="/login" />
            }
            return <WrappedComponent {...this.props}/>;
        }
    }
}

export default memberAreaHOC;
```

Answer (score 3):

There are several way to do that, but I did recently is creating a wrapper function to extended my protected routes.

ie:

```
const memberAreaHOC = WrappedComponent => {
  class MA extends Component {
    render() {
      if ( ! Auth.isAuthenticated()) {
        return <Redirect to="/login" />
      }
      return <WrappedComponent {...this.props}/>;
    }
  }
}
```

and now in your routes definition:

```
<Router>
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
        <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />

        <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={memberAreaHOC(Dashboard)} />

    </Switch>
</Router>
```

You can see, I wrapped `Dashboard` with our new `memberAreaHOC`

`memberAreaHOC(Dashboard)`

Comment: Thanks @Tzook Bar Noy. I am trying to use your solution. But I am getting error. I am trying to use `const memberAreaHOC` as separate component. Could you please edit your code to  use `const memberAreaHOC` as separate component ? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean? Share what you did

Comment: Share your code on the post and what is your error?

Comment: OK, ssaw the updated code and its exactly what I posted. But what is the error you are having? and how did you use it in your routes? show all the needed stuff so I could help

Comment: Thanks. I am getting a black page in `Dashboard` component.

Comment: Well that doesn't help much as I want to know if you have console errors. But in a quick look. The new component we created redirect the user to "/login" path. As I can see in the code you posted you have no "/login" path. The Login component is rendered on "/" so update the "memberAreaHOC" to redirect to that path "/"

Comment: Thanks. I edited "/login" to "/". But the result is as before.

Comment: Share your errors! do console.logs inside the different components so we could see where are things getting or not getting into

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this?

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
    <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
    {
        !Auth.isAuthenticated() && <Redirect to="/" />
    }
    <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
</Switch>
```

Comment: Thanks @Abinthaha. If I use your solution I can not log in. I am staying at login in page. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap `requireAuth` to those components which needs permission to access.
Routes

```
<Route path="/admindashboard" component={requireAuth(App)}/>
```

Create a Higher Order Component to authenticate the user.Generally,`HOC` is created to reuse the functionality where it takes function as an input and gives output as a function.So,in order to authenticate user for each route and for all his authenticated updation or creation it is needed.As the `componentWillMount` will check his authentication before rendering the wrapped component where as the `componentWillUpdate` will check for authetication before updating anything in the authenticated user flow.

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export default function(ComposedComponent) {
  class Authenticate extends React.Component {
    componentWillMount() {
      if (!this.props.isAuthenticated) {
         this.props.history.push('/');
      }
    }

    componentWillUpdate(nextProps) {
      if (!nextProps.isAuthenticated) {
        this.props.history.push('/');
      }
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <ComposedComponent {...this.props} />
      );
    }
  }

  Authenticate.propTypes = {
    isAuthenticated: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
  }

  function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
      isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated
    };
  }

  return withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Authenticate));
}
```

Comment: Why should I need HOC ? Your solution looks complex.

Comment: Generally,HOC is created to reuse the functionality.So,in order to authenticate user for each route and for all his authenticated updation or creation it is needed.As the `componentWillMount` will check his authentication before rendering the wrapped component where as the `componentWillUpdate` will check for authetication before updating anything in the authenticated user flow.Its very simple.